# Reducing 5 VDC to 2.25 VDC to power electromagnet

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage-divider, linear-regulator

I have a custom electromagnet that we are using in a system under development.  It is powered with 2.25 VDC and draws about 1 A at that voltage level.  We need to periodically reverse the current direction on this electromagnet and are planning to use a Toshiba TC 78H653FTG dual h-bridge driver to allow us to use the microcontroller to reverse the direction.

The main system power is from a 12 VDC battery.  Ideally, I'd implement a 2.2, 2.3 or 2.5 V linear regulator but none are available that provide the required current.

I'm considering using an LM7805 5 V regulator with a passive voltage divider but hate the idea of the power being wasted using this method.  What other options do I have?

Comment: Well, the obvious alternative to a linear regulator is a switching one...

Comment: Can you expand on why switching regulators (or off-the-shelf modules) do not fit your application?

Comment: @nanofarad - A switching regulator would probably work.  The ones I looked at were either out of stock or required a lot of external passives to setup.   I'm also getting back into design after decades away and, well, things have certainly changed in the switching area so I'll look at this more closely now.  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: many modest smps controllers, ex LM2596, show the same external component count in the datasheet's examples as a well-implemented lm317 does in it's datasheet.

Comment: There exist complete ICs called _reversible DC motor drive with speed control_, it incorporates bridge and PWM, i used such one successfully. However in term of supply problems, may be it is easier to use MCU to generate PWM with appropriate duty cycle and supply it to general purpose H-bridge.

Comment: _"The ones I looked at were either out of stock..."_ - that's a common problem these days, but in most cases it's only temporary. How many do you need right now?

Comment: Why did you design the custom electromagnet to run at 2.25 V?

Comment: This is a proof of concept situation so we could get by with a couple of units.  And as for the custom electromagnet, its really a hack at this point to prove a concept and it just turned out that the magnetic field we needed with the wire we have and number of windings, etc., etc. ends up drawing too much current above 2.25 and overheating near the material it's exposed to.  Ultimately, we can do a better design and potentially use 5VDC.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of regulating the power before the H bridge driver, use the h bridge driver to regulate the power to the electromagnet. This will require some careful code to avoid asserting a voltage in excess of the electromagnets rating, and some setup of the H bridge driver to limit the allowable current, but it is by far the most efficient and cheapest solution. Consider the block diagram for the intended toshiba H bridge, it already has all the necessary compenents to build an SMPS, with exception of the inductor:
[image: toshiba h bridge datasheet]

Now of course it isn't this easy. the Toshiba H bridge isn't rated to your input voltage (and if your input voltage is actually a lead acid automotive battery on a vehicle, it gets a lot higher than 12V too!), you'll want an "automotive" h bridge chip that's probably rated to 20~28V to survive this application. Secondly you'll need a smaller regulator to power your 5V microcontroller.

datasheet snip from:
https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/semiconductor/product/motor-driver-ics/brushed-dc-motor-driver-ics/detail.TC78H653FTG.html

Comment: "with exception of the inductor".  _Some_ solenoids will make a suitable inductor.  It really depends on how much eddy current losses they experience.  Unless the solenoid is specifically designed for use in a circuit with a switching supply, though, you'll have to try it out and see if it works -- or just use a separate inductor.

Comment: If the microcontroller has a built-in PWM controller, then you could probably do OK by grounding one side and running the other bridge at a duty cycle of \$\frac{2.25 \mathrm V}{12 \mathrm V}\$.  You need some basic understanding of switching amplifier design, though.

Comment: @Bryan - can you share a little more of what you are describing. I want to be sure that I understand.  My first thought is that you're suggesting using the driver to create a square wave output that would drive the electromagnet.  Help me understand a bit more please.  And, we aren't using an automotive battery but you're comment is still valid.  It isn't exactly 12VDC but not more than 14VDC.  I think I already said this in another comment but we use the LM7805 to supply 5VDC to the main board, MCU and it's available to this daughter board.

Comment: @WalterCEden Essentially the H bridge contains all the switching components a synchronous buck converter (voltage-reducing switch mode power supply) would have. You would supply a control law (fixed PWM duty would do as per timwescott's insightful comments) and the AVERAGE voltage across your coil would be 2.25V. Again Tim comes with the insight as your electromagnet probably won't be happy with PWM (eddy currents) so you should add some external inductance. Have a look at microchip's page on sync bucks (https://microchipdeveloper.com/desanl:synchronous-buck-converter-overview).

Comment: @WalterCEden ugh that link is terrible and assumes familiarity with buck converters in general, chase down wikipedia as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter . Essentially yes though, you're correct that I suggest applying square waves to the magnet, though we should probably use an inductor and capacitor to limit eddy currents in the magnet. The square wave would be rather high in frequency, preferably above audible.

Comment: This seems like a cool idea in theory, but I'm not convinced that its actually a good idea. When designing a buck converter, the specifics of the inductor matter quite a lot. Obviously here, you dont care about the stability of the voltage or anything, but I could imagine that you could radiate a large (possibly illegal) amount of EMI, among other issues.

Answer (score 4):

There are many linear regulators that would "work" for you ([LD1086D](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/LD1086DTTRY/2193162) or [LM317T](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nte-electronics-inc/LM317T/11650484) for example), but it would be a huge pain to use them because of the massive amounts of heat generated. 12V in and 2.25V out at 1A means that you would have to get rid of almost 10W of heat, probably requiring fans and rigorous thermal design.

A much simpler and better approach would be to use a switching regulator. You could make one yourself using the many options available on digikey, or you could buy one of the many available online, like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09R49R76K).

Comment: Thanks fro the suggestions.  yes, it's a lot of energy being wasted.   I'll look at your suggestions.  We use the 12VDC because the overall system has several 12VDC motors, solenoids and pumps involved.  We already use the LM7805 to get the 5VDC to power the BeagleBone.  It does require a good heat sink.  We get sufficient battery life even with this waste.  It's an early proof of concept so the ultimate production units will be better.

Comment: heat kills reliability over time, so the less you can generate the better. It looks like the beaglebone can use up to 0.5A steady state (depending on peripherals), so it would not be a bad idea to switch to a switching converter for that too - the beaglebone has internal regulators so noise level on the power line is probably less critical (although still something to watch for)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this.  This is a proof of concept at this point.  I fully expect  A LOT of reliability, cost, and quality engineering to follow this stage.